# Edit Grub menu without additional tools

Tags: debian, ubuntu, windows, grub, boot-loader

i have a triple boot system with ubuntu, debian and windows. grub and the grub menu was installed after the install of ubuntu. is there a way to edit the order entries and there names without installing extra applications like grub customizer? re-order the entries can be done by renaming the scripts in /etc/grub.d but that re-orders also that "advanced options ..." entries. i want to move them all to the bottom of the menu.

it should have existed after an update.

Answer (score 1):

The entries you are concerned about are generated by the /etc/grub.d/10_linux scripts (the comments in /boot/grub.cfg show where the different parts of the file are generated).  Unfortunately, this script doesn't allow any configuration or customization out of the box.

The only thing you can do then, is to manually edit /etc/grub.d/10_linux.  Generally though, that seems like a bad idea as this is a complicated script and editing the script will break easy upgrades of your system.

Answer (score 0):

Basically the grub menu entries are created by their respective operating systems. You can use things like `os-prober` or write into the custom script but probably the easiest way to get what you want would be to chain-load GRUB with another GRUB that loads before it with its own configuration containing something like this in its `grub.cfg`:

```
insmod part_gpt
insmod search_fs_uuid
insmod chain
menuentry "Debian" {
    search --fs-uuid --no-floppy --set=root 1234-abcd
    chainloader ($root)/EFI/debian/grubx64.efi
}
menuentry "Ubuntu" {
    search --fs-uuid --no-floppy --set=root 1234-abcd
    chainloader ($root)/EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi
}
menuentry "Windows" {
    search --fs-uuid --no-floppy --set=root 1234-abcd
    chainloader ($root)/EFI/MICROSOFT/BOOT/bootmgfw.efi
}
```

Where set root is the UUID of the ESP for each boot loader. They are probably all the same.

That also means each boot loader has its own settings and theme as well as advanced entries etc.